# Issue in sagetex with \sagestr

Tags: sagetex

I'm trying to create some maths exercises with SageTeX.
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
x=var("x")
A(x)=(x-2)^2-36
B(x)=1-(2*x-3)^2
formules=[]
for k in [A,B]:
    formules.append(k(x)==factor(k(x)))

enonce=""
for k in formules:
    enonce+=f"""

    ${latex(k)}$"""
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{enonce}
\end{document}
```

The first compilation with pdflatex is OK.
The compilation with sage is OK.
However, the second compilation with pdflatex gives

```
! Paragraph ended before \@newl@bel was complete.
```

Could somebody please explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `log` file tells us what errors LaTeX has found. You said, "The first compilation with pdflatex is OK. The compilation with sage is OK.". This means you should look in the `sout` file to see what information was given back to LaTeX. It looks like this:

[image]

I think `! Paragraph ended before \@newl@bel was complete.` refers to the blank lines in your `.sout` file (an empty line ended the paragraph). I use `raw strings`, which allow for problematic string input such as `\`. This allows me to end the line of calculation with a new line using `\newline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
x=var("x")
A(x)=(x-2)^2-36
B(x)=1-(2*x-3)^2
formules=[]
for k in [A,B]:
    formules.append(k(x)==factor(k(x)))

enonce= r""
for k in formules:
    enonce+=r"\noindent $%s$ \newline"%(latex(k))
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{enonce}
\end{document}
```

The result running in Cocalc has no errors:

[image]

If you wanted an empty line between the two lines shown in the above picture, add another `\newline` as in `enonce+=r"\noindent $%s$ \newline \newline"%(latex(k))`. You can also use `\\` instead of `\newline` or put in a particular amount of space with, for example, `\\[20pt]`.

Comment: Thank you very much
your code  works well for me